# Angular scale is not working on cdk drag preview

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

In my angular application, I have a draggable div. Its parent is scaled down with CSS transform property. While drag the div, the cdk drag preview is not align with its parent's scaling. The div height and width gets back to its initial value which were available before parent scaling.

Comment: try adding the same transform.scale to the class `.cdk-drag-preview`

Comment: @Eliseo, tried this. But no hope !

Comment: You can use a tecnica similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590512/drag-and-drop-image-icons-using-angular/70761246#70761246), in `(mousedown)` you store the "style" and apply to the cdkDragPreview, but sadly, you loose the point when your mouse down (in the SO I use the margin-top and margin-left but this makes that if you has animated, when the element is "dropping goes to left before "re-allocated" )

Comment: Apparently the preview element is attached to the body by default. You need to attach it to the `cdkDrag` parent with `cdkDragPreviewContainer="parent"`.